# How to scrape the Glassdoor Rating using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

The code Im trying to extract the rating number. Im getting Error Index out of Bound, I need to get Rating and Sub Ratings.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time
import re

init_url = 'https://www.glassdoor.co.in/Reviews/DXC-Technology-Reviews- 
E1603125.htm'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(init_url)
time.sleep(5)

i=0
while(i< 11):
    rate1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='rating']")
    rate = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@title='3.0']")[i]    
    print(rate.text)
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the text of the following element instead :-

```
<span class="bigRating strong margRtSm h1">3.3</span>
```

As you can see, it contains your required rating.

Also, since you need different ratings the correct way to do it in a loop is to count the number of reviews available, hence your code will run that many times only.

**Final Code-**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import re

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'//path')
init_url = 'https://www.glassdoor.co.in/Reviews/bangalore-hcl-technologies-reviews-SRCH_IL.0,9_IM1091_KE10,26.htm'

driver.get(init_url)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
i=1
count = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='bigRating strong margRtSm h1']"))
while(i<= count):
    rate = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//span[@class='bigRating strong margRtSm h1'])[" + str(i) + "]")
    print(rate.text)
    i+=1
```

**EDIT -**
Yes, for urls like [this](https://www.glassdoor.co.in/Reviews/DXC-Technology-Reviews-E1603125.htm) you can extract the ratings like this-

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import re

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'//path')
init_url = 'https://www.glassdoor.co.in/Reviews/DXC-Technology-Reviews-E1603125.htm'

driver.get(init_url)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
i=1
count = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='rating']/span[@class='value-title']"))
print count
while(i<= count):
    rate = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//span[@class='rating']/span[@class='value-title'])[" + str(i) + "]")
    print(rate.get_attribute("title"))
    i+=1
```

The rating was stored in the `title` attribute of your `<span>` element so I extracted using `get_attribute("value")`.

**To extract the subratings (like Work/Life balance etc), use below solution -**

```
count = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='undecorated']//div[@class='minor']"))
while(i<= count):
    sub_rating = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//ul[@class='undecorated']//div[@class='minor'])["  + str(i) + "]/following-sibling::span")
    sub_rating_title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//ul[@class='undecorated']//div[@class='minor'])["  + str(i) + "]")
    print(sub_rating_title.get_attribute("innerHTML") , "-" , sub_rating.get_attribute("title"))
    i+=1
```

Console output -

```
Work/Life Balance - 2.0
Culture &amp; Values - 2.0
Career Opportunities - 3.0
Comp &amp; Benefits - 3.0
Senior Management - 2.0
Work/Life Balance - 5.0
Culture &amp; Values - 3.0
Career Opportunities - 4.0
Comp &amp; Benefits - 2.0
Senior Management - 2.0
Work/Life Balance - 3.0
Culture &amp; Values - 3.0
Career Opportunities - 3.0
Comp &amp; Benefits - 3.0
Senior Management - 3.0
Work/Life Balance - 5.0
Culture &amp; Values - 5.0
Career Opportunities - 5.0
Comp &amp; Benefits - 2.0
Senior Management - 2.0
Work/Life Balance - 3.0
Culture &amp; Values - 3.0
Career Opportunities - 2.0
Comp &amp; Benefits - 2.0
Senior Management - 1.0
Work/Life Balance - 3.0
Culture &amp; Values - 3.0
Career Opportunities - 4.0
Comp &amp; Benefits - 5.0
Senior Management - 2.0
Work/Life Balance - 3.0
Culture &amp; Values - 4.0
Career Opportunities - 3.0
Comp &amp; Benefits - 2.0
Senior Management - 3.0
```

Comment: please check the new link for subrating, that is harder to find bcoz it doesnt have any variable listed just <i> star values

Comment: Thank You sir, but is there any way to get the subratings? 
1. Work/Life Balance
2. Culture & Values
3. Career Opportunities 
4. Comp & Benifit
5. Senior Management

Answer (score 1):

To extract the rating number you can use either of the following solution:

- `xpath`:

  ```
  rating = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='ratingsSummary cf']//span[@class='bigRating strong margRtSm h2']").get_attribute("innerHTML")
  ```
- `css_selector`:

  ```
  rating = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.ratingsSummary.cf span.bigRating.strong.margRtSm.h2").get_attribute("innerHTML")
  ```

Comment: please check the new link for subrating, that is harder to find bcoz it doesn't have any variable listed just <i> star values